# Use a route parameter in an attribute in a blazor server page

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am writing this page on a blazor-server application:

```
@page "/pageurl/{param:int}"
@attribute [AnAttribute(param)]

<div>@param</div>

@code
{
   [Parameter]
   public int param { get;set; }
}
```

As you can see, i am trying to pass the param as an argument of my attribute. It does not work. Maybe because when attribute is runned, blazor hasn't parsed parameters.

How can i use a page parameter as an attribute argument ?

Thanks

Comment: Have tried setting the attribute on code behind?

Comment: Yes, same problem

Comment: Attributes are generally used to create compile-time meta information. The attribute you are using will be applied at the page class level. Can you provide your actual use case? That would be more useful to arrive at the solution.

Comment: What are you using the attribute for ?

Comment: It is for security reasons. I want to check if user can access this page for this parameter

Answer (score 1):

Parameters of an attribute must be known at compiletime. (Hard coded)
It makes no difference whether RazorPage or other classes.

The only way to work around this, could be Reflection.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain me how i can do that ?

Comment: To create a instance of a type with reflection is the simple part. But I think it will be tricky to integrate this into the Application itself. Maybe you find inspriation in a "CMS" like application code repository.

Comment: Thanks but I do not understand what you mean with reflection in this case

Comment: With Reflection, you can dynamicly create types, etc. at runtime. A razor/blazor page is a class, so you can assemble the page by reflection. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection).

Comment: Okay but in my case there is no way to access to url and parameters...